# Golang and Gin framework: best practices to connect to Postgresql

Tags: beginner, go, postgresql, web-services

I come from this [question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/219686/gin-framework-project-with-an-endpoint-to-return-a-list-of-users-based-on-their).

**Project**

A very simple [project](https://github.com/josekron/liveops-tool/tree/d1c0307de153b7edb4c5ee22c283e193c7ec2ac8) with Gin framework with an endpoint to return a list of users based on their score.

**Structure**

```
liveops-tool
-- user
---- model
------ user.go
---- service
------ userService.go
---- dao
------ directory.go (interface)
------ userDirectory.go (mock the db)
------ userPostgresDirectory.go
-- main.go
```

**main.go**

```
r.GET("/competition/users", func(c *gin.Context) {
    numUsers, err := strconv.Atoi(c.DefaultQuery("numusers", "6"))
    minScore, err := strconv.Atoi(c.DefaultQuery("minscore", "0"))
    maxScore, err := strconv.Atoi(c.DefaultQuery("maxscore", "2000"))
    fmt.Printf("numUsers: %d , minScore: %d , maxScore: %d \n", numUsers, minScore, maxScore)

    if err == nil {
        var userDirectoryService = userService.NewService(userDirectory.UserPostgrestDirectory{})
        var res = userDirectoryService.GenerateUserListByScore(numUsers, minScore, maxScore)
        c.JSON(http.StatusOK, gin.H{"users": res})
    } else {
        c.JSON(http.StatusBadRequest, gin.H{"users": "no valid"})
    }

})
```

**userService.go**

```
package user

import (
    dao "liveops-tool/user/dao"
    models "liveops-tool/user/models"
)

type UserService struct {
    dir dao.Directory
}

func NewService(dir dao.Directory) *UserService {
    var service = &UserService{
        dir: dir,
    }
    return service
}

// GenerateUserListByScore returns a list of users for a tournament
func (u UserService) GenerateUserListByScore(numUsers, minScore, maxScore int) []models.User {
    return u.dir.SearchUsers(numUsers, minScore, maxScore)
}
```

**userPostgresDirectory.go**

```
package user

import (
    "database/sql"
    "fmt"
    models "liveops-tool/user/models"
    "strings"

    _ "github.com/lib/pq"
)

const (
    host     = "localhost"
    port     = 5432
    user     = "postgres"
    password = "XXXX"
    dbname   = "XXXX"
)

type UserPostgrestDirectory struct {
}

func (u UserPostgrestDirectory) getConnection() *sql.DB {
    psqlInfo := fmt.Sprintf("host=%s port=%d user=%s "+"password=%s dbname=%s sslmode=disable", host, port, user, password, dbname)
    db, err := sql.Open("postgres", psqlInfo)
    checkErr(err)

    return db
}


func (u UserPostgrestDirectory) SearchUsers(numUsers, minScore, maxScore int) []models.User {
    db := u.getConnection()
    defer db.Close()
    err := db.Ping()
    checkErr(err)

    fmt.Println("Successfully connected!")

    rows, err := db.Query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE total_score >= $1 AND total_score <= $2 LIMIT $3", minScore, maxScore, numUsers)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    var users = []models.User{}
    for rows.Next() {
        var id int
        var name string
        var country string
        var total_score int
        err = rows.Scan(&name, &id, &country, &total_score)
        checkErr(err)
        fmt.Println("id | name | country | total_score ")
        fmt.Printf("%3v | %8v | %6v | %6v\n", id, name, country, total_score)
        user := models.User{
            ID:         id,
            Name:       strings.TrimSpace(name),
            Country:    strings.TrimSpace(country),
            TotalScore: total_score,
        }

        users = append(users, user)
    }
    return users
}

func checkErr(err error) {
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}
```

**Questions**

- Is it possible to retrieve the connection directly open or apply some singleton pattern to avoid creating a connection every time that the method SearchUsers is called? I even tried to pass the connection on the UserPostgrestDirectory constructor from main.go but I always get the error "database is closed".

Any other feedback about the code is well received.